# Canvas draw text at same position as TextView

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a `Paint`. I set the text size of it to 150. Then I call `paint.getTextBounds()` to get the bounds of a `String` "g". The result is
**Bounds: Rect(3, -85 - 79, 36), w = 76, h = 121**

If I create a `Bitmap` and use `Canvas.drawText` to draw the "g" on it. What is the correct width and height of the `Bitmap`? What is the correct x and y value for the `drawText` method? So that the bitmap will be exactly the same as a TextView with same text size and text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a bitmap of what a view looks like, use

```
 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
 Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache()
```

Do not try to replicate it yourself, getting all the styles, fonts, and padding correct across multiple versions of Android would be difficult or impossible.